# Converting a NetworkX MultiDiGraph to/from dictionaries

Tags: python, graph, networkx

My reading of the NetworkX [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_dicts.html#networkx.convert.from_dict_of_dicts) suggests this should work, but doesn't seem to?

Consider:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([0, 1])
g.add_edge(0,1)
g.add_edge(0,1)

g.edges()  # returns [(0, 1), (0, 1)]

d = nx.to_dict_of_dicts(g)  # returns {0: {1: {0: {}, 1: {}}}, 1: {}}

g2 = nx.from_dict_of_dicts(d, multigraph_input=True)
# or, equivalently?, g2 = MultiDiGraph(d)

g2.edges()  # only returns [(0,1)]
```

Am I making a trivial error here, or is this a bug?

For my application, I've found a better alternative which was to serialize using `networkx.readwrite.json_graph` but I thought I'd leave the question here in case it's useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default graph output for `nx.from_dict_of_dicts()` appears to be a simple graph.

```
>>> g2
<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x10877add0>
```

Try creating a new empty graph of the same type as that which output you'd desire--so in your case a MultiDiGraph. Then use the `create_using` parameter of `nx.from_dict_of_dicts()` to make sure your new graph is of that type:

```
>>> G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
>>> g3 = nx.from_dict_of_dicts(d, multigraph_input=True, create_using=G)
>>> g3.edges()
[(0, 1), (0, 1)]
>>> g3
<networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph at 0x1087a7190>
```

Success!

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks :) I would have thought `multigraph_input=True` would have taken care of this, missed the `create_using` arg.